# Datazen (excel on a network share as source for data)

Tags: excel, data-import, data-connections, datazen-server

I couldn’t find any other place where I could get support on `Datazen`.
Maybe here I'll have some luck with this.

I have a problem when I try to create Data connection from Datazen control panel, using option Excel Document in a network share. I tried to set filepath in different ways like:

```
c:\excel_source\test2.xlsx (this is where is XLSX file located on server)
```

Also tried to create network share

```
\\DATAZEN\excel_source
\\DATAZEN\excel_source\test2.xlsx
```

But every time I’ve received `System.exception` and 
File looks like a simple table with two columns on sheet1
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e

I even tried to check datazen logs, but nothing interesting I had found there:

> 2016-03-02 09:08:33.1268
>   Datazen.Server.Service.Api.Controllers.AdministrationController
>   Datazen.Server.Core.Services.DataService|Error: Выдано исключение типа
>   “System.Exception”. в
>   Datazen.Server.Core.Services.DataService.RequestConnectionTest(String
>   execid, String hubid, DataConnectionDto connection)

If I use simple excel import in dashboard data source settings – everything works perfect with xlsx file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for Datazen support, and not a programming question. To contact the appropriate support professional, I would suggest emailing support@datazen.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, 
First of all I installed AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.
And then went throught this solution:
http://christopherfinlan.com/2015/05/23/how-to-use-an-excel-data-source-for-kpis-in-datazen/